# Find the smallest disk in complex plane containing the eigenvalues of a matrix (NBHM 2012)

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the given matrix

$$\left[\begin{matrix}1& -2& 3& -2 \\1& 1& 0& 3\\-1& 1& 1& -1\\0& -3& 1& 1&\end{matrix}\right]$$

Find out the smallest disk like ($|z-1| < r$ ) in the complex plane containing the eigenvalues of the given matrix.

One easiest method is to find out the eigenvalues from the characteristic equation of the matrix. I can do it so no problem with it.

I am looking for a method to solve the problem without the above method that can be evaluated in very short time. This type of method is possible, I believe.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Were you thinking of [*Gerschgorin disks*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GershgorinCircleTheorem.html) or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [*Gerschgorin Disks*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GershgorinCircleTheorem.html) approach, we have:

- $D_1 = \{|z-1| \le 7\}$
- $D_2 = \{|z-1| \le 4\}$
- $D_3 = \{|z-1| \le 3\}$
- $D_4 = \{|z-1| \le 4\}$
- $D_A = D_1 \cup D_2 \cup D_3\cup  D_4$ - This is the Gerschgorin domain for all of the eigenvalues.

The actual eigenvalues are:

- $\lambda_{1,2} = 0.495567~ \pm ~ 3.83314 i$
- $\lambda_{3,4} = 1.50443 ~ \pm ~0.90331 i$

Comment: Thank you for your information. It is totally a new concept to me. Tonight I saw it in a question paper. Is there any other method? You have give a link. Please mention a book where I shall get this method.

Comment: Are there any other method for such type of problems. I was studying your references. The answer given by question setters is $|z - 1| \leq 6$ but here we are getting $|z - 1| \leq 7$. So I am asking.

Comment: Entries are correct. Thank you for your support. They may have mistake.

Comment: Yes it should be.

Comment: No, I haven't seen the book until a recent comment I saw to an earlier answer of mine, pointing to that book as another recommendation. Have you read it?

Comment: This does **not answer the question** in a correct way (even the disk $|z-1|<6$ the question setter claimed is obviously not correct). Even in "$\|\cdot\|_1$"-norm you get that $r$ can be chosen smaller than $5$. However, the question **cannot** be answered properly, hence a smallest **compact disk** with radius $\hat r$ around $1$ containing all eigenvalues can be found, but the question asks for an open disk. But for any $r>\hat r$ the disk with radius $(r-\hat r )/ 2$ still contains all eigenvalues of $A$

Answer (score 2):

For this particular problem, the matrix (say $A$) turns out to have two pairs of conjugate eigenvalues $\lambda,\bar{\lambda},\mu,\bar{\mu}$. The center of the required disc is therefore $\frac14\operatorname{trace}(A)$ and the radius is $|\lambda-\frac14\operatorname{trace}(A)|$. So, even if you can infer by some clever argument that $A$ has two pairs of conjugate eigenvalues, you still have to calculate one eigenvalue of $A$. So, I don't think you can solve the problem in a simple manner without calculating the spectrum of $A$.

Comment: This is a new idea to me. Thank you for this answer. Please give some reference if possible.